# down image[Reflaction one] not displaying as upper image

Tags: android

In my application i have two images original upper image and down reflection one. SO i made sample application and it is working fine as specified in this screenshot. [image: Sample app screenshot]

now i want to implement same in my application which has complex layout file. SO the code snippt is as follow. but 2nd image is always coming small with no respect of padding. CEnter point of both image is same but the width of down image is most probably half of it. I tried to play with margin but even if i increase it there is no change. let me know if you have any question. the screen and code snippt of my real application and image is as follow. i do not know why it is not working same way as it is working in sample app. [image]

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="32.5px"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/top_padding"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"></View>

        <VideoView android:id="@+id/video_view"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_padding"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </VideoView>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/video_image_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/top_padding"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_padding" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:src="@drawable/anna" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ImageView>

        <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="32.5px"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/bottom_padding"
            android:background="#FFFF0000"></View>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/video_image_view_reflection"

            android:layout_below="@+id/video_image_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FF00FF00" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/video_image_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="32.5px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32.5px"
            android:src="@drawable/anna"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ImageView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: provide image of anna as well so we can try it

Comment: that you can get from google. and you can try with any image.

Comment: Ok then you can do google and try your luck to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modifications:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/video_image_view"
  android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/top_padding"
  android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_padding" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:src="@drawable/anna" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
 </ImageView>
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="32.5px"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/bottom_padding"
  android:background="#FFFF0000" ></View>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/video_image_view_reflection"
  android:layout_below="@+id/video_image_view" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:background="#FF00FF00" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/video_image_view"
  android:layout_marginTop="32.5px"
  android:layout_marginBottom="32.5px"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:scaleType="matrix"
  android:src="@drawable/anna"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ImageView>
```